# Multiuser chat OMEMO encrypted messages and MAM (XEP-0313)

Tags: openfire, omemo

i am trying to use the Monitoring plugin for offline storage of OMEMO encrypted multi user chat messages. The Monitoring plugin for Openfire does not save this type of messages, because their stanzas do not contain the body element. Is this a missing functionality in the Monitoring plugin (OMEMO with XEP-0313) or is it a conscious decision? And if it is a conscious decision what are the reasons?
Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you ask the authors of the plug-in? For example using the Openfire forum.

Answer (score 1):

Related [thread](https://discourse.igniterealtime.org/t/message-sent-without-body-not-getting-into-offline-user-whever-its-online/84772) on the Ignite Realtime forums.